# Determine if a database is an azure database

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Is it ok to assume that if the server name ends with "database.windows.net" that the database is hosted on azure?

I tried executing this code on my azure db:

```
SELECT CASE ServerProperty('EngineEdition')
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Personal'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Standard'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Enterprise'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Express'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'SQL Database'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Azure Synapse Analytics'
         WHEN 8 THEN 'Azure SQL Managed Instance'
         WHEN 9 THEN 'Azure SQL Edge'
         WHEN 11 THEN 'Azure Synapse serverless SQL pool'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
       END
```

But it returned "SQL Database"...

How can I reliably discern if a database or sql server is hosted on azure?

I should be writing the code to determine this in c#

right now it might be something like:

```
if (serverName.Contains("database.windows.net"))
   {
            //is on azure 
   }
   else
   {
            //is not hosted on azure
   }
```

Comment: One could conceivably have a server name "database.windows.net.mysite.com" or even override their DNS so that "server.database.windows.net" points to an on-prem database.  One could also host a database in Azure and not have a server name that ends in database.windows.net. Why do you need to know whether the database is hosted in Azure or not?

Comment: `SQL Database` === `Azure SQL Database`. In other words, when the function returns 5, it's Azure SQL Database. Your code just shortens that and leaves out the 'Azure' for whatever reason.

Comment: `EngineEdition` will be reflect Standard, Enterprise, etc. when the SQL Server instance is hosted by an Azure VM. Not sure if you care where a physical machine or VM is hosted.

Comment: select @@version as version; of select serverproperty('Edition') as [edition];

Comment: I think this link can help you https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/blog/checking-your-sql-azure-server-connection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with your code I also got the same issue.
Image for reference:

[image]

We can replace 'Azure SQL Database' in place of 'SQL Database'.
I used below code to determine the database:

```
SELECT  CASE
WHEN  ServerProperty('Edition') =  'SQL Azure'
     THEN  'Azure SQL Database'
     ELSE  'Not Azure SQL Database'  END  AS server_version;
```

[image]